# How to find a given game room in all TS3 servers?

Tags: windows, teamspeak

I want to find a particular room (for example, a room related to Civilization V) in [TeamSpeak 3](http://www.teamspeak.com/), but I can't enter each server manually. How do I do it?

Comment: I'll mention that this does _not_ belong on Gaming. The only videogame related feature here is that Jader wants to search rooms by a string that happens to be the name of a videogame.